# Loading a NumericUpDown value from Properties.Settings.Default?

Tags: c#, winforms

My program saves `TextBoxes` via [Properties.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) so that I can close and open the program and it'll remember what's in it. That part works. However, the program also has some `NumericUpDown` boxes that I'd like the values to be saved as well, but the problem is that I can't seem to get it to load. Here's my code:

Loading:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   numericUpDown1.Value = Settings.Default["H1"].ToString();
}
```

Saving:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default["H1"] = numericUpDown1.Value;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The error is at

```
Settings.Default["H1"].ToString();
```

and the message is

> Error 1: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'

Comment: you should maybe debug your program & see whether the H1 can be casted or not.

Answer (score 2):

The `Value` property expects a `Decimal` value to be assigned to it but you were trying to assign `string`. It should be

```
numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Settings.Default["H1"].ToString());
```